# Python car sales code issue

Tags: python

Ok so, I have an assignment to make a carsales program which is suppose to calculate how much the salesperson will make in a week. I already know how much all the cars sell for and how much commission he makes. Here is my code:

```
def main():

    print ('This program will compute the comission earned for the week based on your sales for the week.')
    car_number = float(input('Enter number of cars sold :'))

    def calculate_total(car_number,price,commission_rate):
        price = 32,500.00
        commission_rate = .025
        calculate_total = car_number * price * commission_rate
        return calculate_total(car_number)
    print('The weekly gross pay is $',calculate_total)


main()
```

The program isn't working for some reason but I decided to submit it to my professor anyway. He then replied by saying that I wasn't asked to create a new function and that I have to delete it and work just in main. Can someone please tell me what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i did not saw the complete question before but anyway this is the correct answer without a function
The keywords `try` and `except` are for error handling. If you give as input something invalid let's say a letter instead of number will throw a message
(`Could not convert input data to a float.`)

```
def main():
    print ('This program will compute the comission earned for the week based on your sales for the week.')
    try:
        #before: car_number = float(raw_input('Enter number of cars sold :'))
        car_number = float(input('Enter number of cars sold :'))

    except ValueError:
        #before: print 'Could not convert input data to a float.'
        print('Could not convert input data to a float.')
    print('The weekly gross pay is ${}'.format(car_number * 32500.00 * 0.025 )))

main()
```

If you don't even want `main()` function here is the answer:

```
print ('This program will compute the comission earned for the week based on your sales for the week.')
try:
    car_number = float(input('Enter number of cars sold :'))

except ValueError:
    print('Could not convert input data to a float.')
print('The weekly gross pay is ${}'.format(car_number * 32500.00 * 0.025 )))
```

Comment: I just tried it and it said that parentheses were missing after print so I added those and now I get this error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sa6ko/Desktop/sgagsagsagsa.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Sa6ko/Desktop/sgagsagsagsa.py", line 4, in main
    car_number = float(raw_input('Enter number of cars sold :'))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Jorge, you're still using a function, I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @spirulence i desagree. The `main()` is a function but is also the starting point of the program so does not count. Anyway i will post it without...

Comment: Can't win em all, I guess. :) @Aleksandar, if this answer worked, please accept it.

Comment: Yes it worked, and I will accept it! :) Thank you guys for your help, I appreciate it, have a wonderful day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

'Working in main' as your professor said means that you don't define any functions. All your code just sits in the file, without any `def ...` statements. I know that's probably not clear. Here's an example:

```
import os

print "Your current working directory is:"
print os.getcwd()
```

This kind of programming has more the feel of a 'script' - you're not defining parts of the program that you're going to use more than once, and you're not taking the trouble to break down what the program does into single-purpose functions.

Second, you've entered price in such a way that Python thinks you're creating a tuple of numbers instead of a single value.

`price = 32,500.00` is interpreted by Python as creating a tuple, with values `32` and `500.00` in it. What you actually want is: `price = 32500.00`.

---

I broke down and completed the process for you.

```
print ('This program will compute the comission earned for the week based on your sales for the week.')

car_number = float(input('Enter number of cars sold :'))
price = 32500.00
commission_rate = .025
calculate_total = car_number * price * commission_rate

print('The weekly gross pay is $',calculate_total)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what exactly do I need to change in my code in order to get rid of the def and make it work? If it's not a problem can you re-write the code or at least tell me the steps to fix it? Thanks again, sorry for asking so much but like I said im new to programming so...

Comment: All you should need to do is remove the `def main():`, remove indentation, and remove the last line `main()`.

Comment: And there's no need to be sorry - we were all new to programming at one time, and most of us didn't have a great resource like Stack Overflow at our fingertips! Continue to ask questions, and learn, and give back when you can, and good stuff will happen.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the additional function definition for calculate_total - do the same process for it.

Comment: So all I do is remove the def main():, the main on the bottom and also what do I do to the calculate_total line?

Comment: It's hard for me to explain without doing. Here's a comparative gist: https://gist.github.com/spirulence/34301f4fd09407bc7476

What I've done is taken out all the indentation and functions, and just placed your program statements one after the other. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error:                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sa6ko/Desktop/assgagsasag.py", line 6, in <module>
    calculate_total = car_number * price * commission_rate
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Yeah I copied your code and I get the error i showed you :(

Comment: By the way if it helps I'm using the latest python 3.4.2 version

Comment: You're not using the latest version, I get no such error.

Comment: Hmm that's weird... which version are you using? The only reason i'm using 3.4.2 because our professor told us that is the latest one that we need to use..

Comment: I should have been more clear. I updated the code again, you've still got the version with a misplaced comma. Copy my code, run again, tell me if it works. :)

Comment: We should take this to IRC or something - I hang out in ##programming on freenode a lot.

Comment: It's fine dude, the code that Jorge gave me worked perfectly :) Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I'm glad there are people like you guys here that can really help me, I hope in the near future I'l be the one helping other people ! :)